# react native webview doesn't seem to support speech to text and microphone is not showing the text when speech is occurring

Tags: javascript, react-native, webview

React Native Webview doesn't seem to support speech to text and microphone is not showing the text when speech is occurring. Any ideas how to solve this? The website with speech to text recognition is here: https://htcschatbot.azurewebsites.net/.
Here is my code:

```
export default function App() {
   return (
     <WebView
       source={{
         uri: "https://htcschatbot.azurewebsites.net/",
       }}
       javaScriptEnabled={true}
       domStorageEnabled={true}
       style={styles.view}
     />
   );
 }

 const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   view: {
     marginTop: 40,
   },
 });
```

I tried with DOM, and nothing works. I don't know what API to use or how to use DOM with this. Code samples with my given code appreciated.